# Reapply bindings in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I basically want to reapply bindings on the same page for the different objects, but there is strange behavior. After I reapply the binding, the list of items is lost.

Please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/baio/9UcUs/5/

What to do?

Comment: This may not anwer you question directly but a more standard approach with knockout is to bind your view model and then alter then contents of the model rather than change the entire model each time. See http://jsfiddle.net/9UcUs/8/ for an example.

Comment: Relevant code should always be ***in*** the question, not just linked (not even jsFiddle).

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is that it's not supported. The long answer is that there are some ways around it. One way is to call `cleanNode` before `applyBindings`, but this doesn't clear event handlers. Another way is to wrap your view model in an observable and then update that observable to reapply bindings; this works much better, but still has a slight problem (see below).

Here is your example using the observable view model method: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/9UcUs/9/

The only problem I've found with using an observable view model is that event handlers are not completely updated with the new view model. They will call the correct function in the new view model, but the `this` and `data` values will be for the original view model.

Edit:

Knockout 3.0 (currently scheduled for release this month) fully supports observable view models. There still could be issues with custom bindings, but hopefully all this will be documented soon.

Comment: Fast-forward to KO v 3.5, and it works for me. At least, it passed my cursory initial testing

Answer (score 5):

you can bind the same viewmodel to different elements,  you need specify the element you want to apply your binding to.

```
ko.applyBindings(vm, $('#yourul'));

ko.applyBindings(vm, $('#div'));
```

Comment: remember that Knockout is not jQuery dependent: use `$('#yourul')[0]` and `$('#div')[0]` instead

Answer (score 0):

Doing:

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('#somejQObj')[0]);
```

Works as stated in the comments of @fengd's answer. Currently have a table that is populated by a foreach statement, that has expandable rows that each one has a dynamically added sub-table that is also populated by a foreach statement. After each sub-table is dynamically inserted doing the above sets the bindings for the sub-table and populates the data.