# Apply visible binding progmatically with knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am writing a custom binding but as part of it I need to apply a data bind for the visible binding via javascript. There seems to be little problem in getting it to work up front, however when the observable being used is updated the binding does not get re-evaluated.

Upon looking in the source code for KO there is no init event so not sure if some space magic happens at some layer to get it to re-evaluate the dom elements on the observable changing but I am unable to find this info.

So is there some specific way to create an artificial binding which re-evaluates, or do I need to create my own subscribe callback to keep re-evaluating the visible binding?

Here is the code I am using:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.visible.update(element, isVisibleObservable, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);
```

I know I could write my own show and hide logic, but I just thought it would be simpler on first glance to use the existing binding which does it under the hood.

Here is a simple example of the scenario with the code usage:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.someCustomBinding = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        var customBindings = allBindings.someCustomBinding;
        var someReferencedElement = $(customBindings.target)[0];

        var isVisible = (customBindings.isDefault) ? true : false;
        var visibleObservable = ko.observable(isVisible);
        knockout.bindingHandlers.visible.update(someReferencedElement, visibleObservable, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);

        element.onclick = function() { 
            var toggledValue = !visibleObservable();
            visibleObservable(toggledValue) 
        };
    }
};
```

I have heavily simplified the scenario, so removed validation of parameters etc but that should highlight the main usage and issue. When I click on the element with the custom binding it is toggling the value (as I can see this in the debugger) although it does not update the visibility of the referenced DOM element.

Comment: have you got more code you can share so we can try to recreate the issue?

Comment: I am not sure if it is an issue or works as expected, I can provide more information but the crux of the usage is displayed above, will add a wrapper to give more of an indication as to how its being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this post -

[Reapply bindings in knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314736/reapply-bindings-in-knockout)

The problem is that you can add new bindings to Knockout and force them to re-evaluate but what you are trying to do is apply a binding to existing bindings and clean the node and re-evaluate, which is a grey area as shown in that question I linked.  At this point I would implement a custom binding handler to do what you are trying to do using show/hide logic there until a more stable solution can be found.

You could just incorporate the code into your custom binding handler for now -

```
ko.bindingHandlers['visible'] = {
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var isCurrentlyVisible = !(element.style.display == "none");
        if (value && !isCurrentlyVisible)
            element.style.display = "";
        else if ((!value) && isCurrentlyVisible)
            element.style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

If you show a better example and include your binding handler I can help update it.

Comment: Yeah I was originally thinking of this, and as I have jquery required I can simplify it quite a lot. I will give it a short while longer incase there are any other good responses but this seems like the winner so far :)

Comment: Sure, one thing to remember is when you do implement it make sure that you get and unwrap the value like shown so that the binding subscribes to the observable properly.

Comment: Yeah like I said I just quickly mocked up the above leaving out the unwrapping and value wrapper for pass through. Will give you the answer as it seems like there is no simple way to have the update binding re-evaluate without calling it in the update method of mine. However you have a link as to why re applying bindings is bad so it is good content. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The visible binding `update` function needs to be called from your `update` function or it will not function correctly.  Just create an update function and move the call.  Also, the 2nd argument is a `valueAccessor`, not the raw observable:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.someCustomBinding = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        var customBindings = allBindings.someCustomBinding;
        var someReferencedElement = $(customBindings.target)[0];

        var isVisible = (customBindings.isDefault) ? true : false;
        var visibleObservable = ko.observable(isVisible);
        var visibleValueAccessor = function () { return visibleObservable; };

        // store the stuff as data on the element so that
        // it can be found in the update call
        var data = { element: somereferencedElement, v: visibleValueAccessor };
        ko.utils.domData.set(element, "__customBinding", data);

        element.onclick = function() { 
            var toggledValue = !visibleObservable();
            visibleObservable(toggledValue) 
        };
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var data = ko.utils.domData.get(element, "__customBinding");
        knockout.bindingHandlers.visible.update(data.element, data.v, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);
    }
};
```